# Fragment Recycle View (with Card) is duplicated and overalped

Tags: java, android, xml

**SOLVED**:

### Removing the LinearLayoutManager will solve this. Thanks!

I am writing an Android app view with Recycle View and Card style with 2 columns. But strangely, it has another recycle view duplicated layered behind which not scrollable.

Please help advise :)

[image]

**EDIT**:
It is inside a Fragment. Fragment's code

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View fragmentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_discover, container, false);

        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) fragmentView.findViewById(R.id.rv_merchants); 
         recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        final LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(fragmentView.getContext());

        RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(fragmentView.getContext(), 2);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());

        data = new ArrayList<ExampleDataModel>();
        for (int i = 0; i < DA_ExampleDataModel.nameArray.length; i++) {
            data.add(new ExampleDataModel(
                    DA_ExampleDataModel.nameArray[i],
                    DA_ExampleDataModel.versionArray[i],
                    DA_ExampleDataModel.id_[i],
                    DA_ExampleDataModel.drawableArray[i]
            ));
        }

      layoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
      adapter = new RV_DiscoveryMerchant(data);

        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

            return fragmentView;  


 }
```

Fragment's XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="15dp"
    android:paddingLeft="15dp"
    android:paddingRight="0dp"
    android:paddingTop="15dp"
    tools:context=".Fragment.DiscoverFragment"> 

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:text="Android version"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Headline"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rv_merchants"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scrollbars="vertical" />


 </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Please add the code you use to render your UI - this image isn't enough to go on.

Comment: Hi @PPartisan, code for the fragment and xml is added

Comment: that `LinearLayoutManager` is useless, for certain.

Comment: Thanks - and where do you add this fragment? Is it dynamically with a `FragmentManager`, or via xml?

Comment: Hi @PPartisan, its solved by removing the Linear Layout Manager, thanks to Martin Zeitler!

Comment: Are you sure? That doesn't make any sense - that layoutmanager was useless, but it isn't applied anywhere so should be harmless.